# Imap4 client command LSUB

Tags: delphi, email, imap, indy10

I have a problem with `function TIdIMAP4.ListSubscribedMailBoxes(AMailBoxList: TStrings): Boolean;` with this implementation :

```
function TIdIMAP4.ListSubscribedMailBoxes(AMailBoxList: TStrings): Boolean;
begin
  {CC2: This is one of the few cases where the server can return only "OK     completed"
  meaning that the user has no subscribed mailboxes.}   
    Result := False;
    CheckConnectionState([csAuthenticated, csSelected]);
    SendCmd(NewCmdCounter, IMAP4Commands[cmdLSub] + ' "" *',
      [IMAP4Commands[cmdList], IMAP4Commands[cmdLSub]]);   {Do not Localize}
    if LastCmdResult.Code = IMAP_OK then begin
      // ds - fixed bug # 506026
      ParseLSubResult(AMailBoxList, LastCmdResult.Text);
      Result := True;
    end;
end;
```

When I debug I see that the `LastCmdResult.Text` stringlist is empty, but the `LastCmdResult.FormattedReply` stringlist has all folders on my email server (Inbox, Sent, Trash, ...). When I tried to use `LastCmdResult.FormattedReply` count or text, it had immediately lost its data and gave `LastCmdResult.FormattedReply.Count=0` and `LastCmdResult.FormattedReply.Text=''`. So I'd like to know if there is a way to enter the data inside `LastCmdResult.FormattedReply` and get my email server folders or there is another way to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a problem with function `TIdIMAP4.ListSubscribedMailBoxes(AMailBoxList: TStrings): Boolean;` with this implementation :

Works fine for me when I try it using the latest SVN version of Indy.

> When I debug I see that the `LastCmdResult.Text` stringlist is empty, but the `LastCmdResult.FormattedReply` stringlist has all folders on my email server (Inbox, Sent, Trash, ...).

When I run it, the opposite happens.  `LastCmdResult.Text` contains the expected text, and `LastCmdResult.FFormattedReply` is empty (notice I mention the `FFormattedReply` data member directly, see below).

> When I tried to use `LastCmdResult.FormattedReply` count or text, it had immediately lost its data and gave `LastCmdResult.FormattedReply.Count=0` and `LastCmdResult.FormattedReply.Text=''`.

That is by design.  The `FormattedReply` property is intended to be used by a client to parse a server reply so it can populate `TIdReply`'s property values, and to be used by a server to generate a new reply using TIdReply's property values.  So, you cannot read from the `FormattedReply` property on the client side.

> So I'd like to know if there is a way to enter the data inside `LastCmdResult.FormattedReply` and get my email server folders or there is another way to solve my problem ?

The whole purpose of `ListSubscribedMailBoxes()` is to return the folder names in the `AMailBoxList` parameter.  If that is not working for you, then either

1. you are using a older/buggy version of Indy.
2. your server is sending the data in a format that TIdIMAP4 is not able to parse.

Without knowing which version of Indy you are actually using, or what the server's reply data actually looks like, there is no way to diagnose your issue one way or the other.

Comment: I connect to the imap server of yahoo (``imap.mail.yahoo.com`` on port ``993`` with username and password) and this is how ``FormattedReply`` stringlist looks like :

    [0]=* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Bulk Mail"
    [1]=* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Draft"
    [2]=* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Inbox"
    [3]=* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent"
    [4]=* LSUB (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Trash"
    [5]=C3 OK LSUB Completed
The version of indy I use is ``10.6.2.5263``

Comment: I've just upgraded my Indy to the latest from ``https://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/`` - ``Indy10_5283.zip`` and the problem remains.

Comment: Works fine for me when I connect to Gmail's IMAP server. I will test with Yahoo's and report back.

Comment: I tested with Yahoo's IMAP, as well as GoDaddy's.  Both `ListMailBoxes()` and `ListSubscribedMailBoxes()` worked fine, the `AMailBoxList` parameter received the list of mailbox names in both cases.  So what is the actual problem you are having? That your `AMailBoxList` object is not being populated at all? Or that it is, but not the way you expect? Or that you are simply debugging inside Indy's source and do not understand how it is working internally?

Comment: The problem is that ``AMailBoxList`` object is not being populated at all and I also don't perfectly understand what Indy does internally.

Comment: Like I said, I have now tested the methods on 3 different IMAP servers (Yahoo, Gmail, and GoDaddy) using the latest version of Indy, and `AMailBoxList` *DOES* get populated on all of them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I guess someone probably messed up my code. I don't see any other explanation why it's not working for me...